# How to get notifications from Oozie through REST interface?

Tags: node.js, rest, oozie

I'm developing a Node.js process that submits jobs through the Oozie REST interface. I'd like to get notifications on my jobs' status (succeeded, failed, killed etc.). I know I can poll the `/v2/job/:jobId` endpoint every *n* seconds, but would rather subscribe to notifications, so I can surface them to the client side in a timely manner.

I went over the entire [web API documentation](http://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.0.1/WebServicesAPI.html), and found there's a `/v2/sla` endpoint, but I cannot find any documentation on how to use it. The only thing I could Google was someone using a Java queue to receive JMS messages (an [article on Cloudera](http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh5/cdh/5/oozie/AG_Install.html#Notifications_Configuration) that I'm not sure is applicable). I'd like to get something more JavaScript-y - if possible.

Can someone point me at the right documentation/direction on how to get Oozie notifications?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specify "oozie.wf.workflow.notification.url" in your job.properties file.  This is the URL it will call when the job has completed.

Workflow Notifications: http://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.0.1/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html